# which database layout would better for a login system?

Tags: mysql

okay so I have two ways of doing my database I have two different users with different fields but that will mean that I need two different tables and that will mean more coding etc.. that's inefficient

the users table:

```
first_name, Last_name, email, password, dis,
```

the other user table:

```
business_name, business_email, password, dis, posts,
```

I need help how do you recommend I do my login? with 2 different tables should I combine them? or should I have two login pages or something?

I am using PHP and MySQL this is not and school project this is for a commercial website I know most of you say I need to use a framework but I don't want to so.

Comment: why do you use 2 different tables?

Comment: because those fields are not the same look at the code that I supplied above different things need to be done as the one will have extra fields that the others won't have...

Comment: Why don't you add a 'role' if you have different types of users?

Comment: I want to down-vote because of 1) the remark "please don't downvote"   2) the last sentence "alert("thanks & have a nic3 day");"  (and because the question is opinion-based...)

Comment: I think it's more to the developer's requirement and dependent on the project itself. No one can really tell you how many tables you need on a project you're working with. So far all my personal projects only uses one table for "Login" and at least another table to store a detailed profile of the user.

Comment: @Luuk I fixed it I am terribly sorry for my mistakes thanks for the edit

Comment: @tcadidot0 i also usually have only one table for users log in and register but this project requires different tables as the two users have a lot of different properties etc...

Comment: This is the classic single table inheritance vs multi table (class) inheritance problem.  Both are valid data modelling techniques, it really boils down your specific business requirements which one to use!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Approach - You can login with user type if he has business email or not and use 2 separate tables like you mentioned.
Second Approach - If your service needs to have both user and business email for each user, then you can even merge the tables for login. You can define one to NOT NULL.

Comment: hey actually that's a simple approach why didn't I think of that lmao I love it thanks a lot buddy I will definitely use the first approach have a good day and stay safe from covid-19

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64783170/is-this-login-page-the-correct-way-of-doing-it this is how i implemented your answer please check if for me :) @Seema

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can try to use this

```
user (user_id,first_name, Last_name, email, password, dis, role)

business(business_name,  posts, user_id)
```

and you can add relations between user and business table. you can add role for different types of users with type data enum('type1','type2')

Comment: i will try this thanks

Comment: If this answer usefull, give me a 'upvote' and 'accept'

Comment: I, unfortunately, don't have enough points to up-vote and I didn't go with your methods but instead with @seema's method